# Can I use regex to parse a word out of a phrase?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse table names from a list of insert statements, all of which are of the form `insert into table_a`. For that statement, I would like to find the name `table_a`.

My current code to do this is pretty clunky, could this be accomplished with regex?

```
    int index = query.indexOf("insert into");
    if (index >= 0) {
        query = query.substring(index + "insert into".length());
        query = query.trim();

        index = query.indexOf(" ");
        if (index >= 0)
            return query.substring(0, index);
        else
            return query; // tablename is last word in query
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Have you tried something at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regular expressions should help here:

```
String input = "INSERT INTO tableA ... INSERT INTO tableB";
String pattern = "insert into ([\\s]+)";
List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    tables.add(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

tableA
tableB
```

### Demo

Note that I assume your table names don't have spaces.  If they do, then a better approach would be to match up until the opening parenthesis, assuming your insert statements are standard SQL.

Comment: This is slightly stricter than OP's version, since it requires exactly 1 space character before the table name.

Comment: @shmosel On a cell phone...hard to test

Comment: @shmosel I will modify with `\\s+`

Comment: I think changing to `[a-z]` was a mistake. It can reject valid table names.

Comment: @shmosel You're right, though the exact range of characters available for a table name depends on the database.  I have updated to match any non whitespace character as the table name.  Probably too broad, but probably better than what I had.

Comment: `\`foo bar\`` is also a valid table name in MySQL, but hopefully that's out of scope here.

Comment: Yeah...if the OP is asking for a SQL parser, I'd say it's almost out of scope for a single SO question/answer.  SQL Server escapes with brackets, e.g. `[foo bar]`, others use double quotes `"foo bar"`.